# .html removal from URL using .htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a static website - a bunch of static html pages. I am trying to remove .html part from the URL of my webpages. I have used an .htaccess file with the following code to do that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

However, I am getting a 404 error. For example:

> The requested URL /home/username/public_html/contact.html was not found on this server.

Ideally, it should redirect to /~username/contact.html.

**Addition information** 
When I used "Options -MultiViews" line above the code it is giving the following error:

> 500 Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) server is used here.

Why I am facing this problem? Is root is automatically getting changed from `public_html/` folder?

EDIT:

Directory Structure:

- Username

  - .gnome2 (there are empty folders inside it)
  - .mozilla (there are empty folders inside it)
  - public_html (I have put css, fonts, js, etc folders and .htaccess, contact.html, index.html, etc files here.)
  - .bash_logout
  - .bash_profile
  - .bashrc

Username folder is under universitynameuniverse folder (whose other folders I cannot see).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

That’s it! You can now link pages inside the HTML document without needing to add the extension of the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I am getting the same 404 not found error.

Comment: Please ensure your link : <a href="http://domain.com/about" title="About Us">About Us</a>

Comment: I have used <a href="http://domain.com/~username/contact">Contact</a>. But still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```bsh
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
    RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
## Results
# ~user/contact => ~user/contact.html (only if file exists)
```

It only works if the `~user/` directory actually exists on the filesystem.

If you need an external redirect instead, append an `R` flag to the RewriteRule directive.

The problem with your rewrite rule is that it's appending a `.html` suffix to the whole `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable which will probably result in a 404.

---

### Update

Re-reading your question I noted that you want to map the `~user` part to somewhere out of the apache webroot. In this case, try this:

```bsh
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/~(.+)/(.+)$
    RewriteCond /home/%1/public_html/%2.html -f
    RewriteRule . /home/%1/public_html/%2.html [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
## Results
# ~user/contact => /home/user/public_html/contact.html (only if file exists)
```

Comment: It is giving exactly the same 404 error: 

The requested URL /home/username/public_html/contact.html was not found on this server.

To be clear, I expect, example.com/~username/contact should redirect to example.com/~username/contact.html. But that is not happening.

Comment: It's tested and it works on a vanilla apache installation. Does the `~user/` directory actually exists on the filesystem? Do you have anything else in your htaccess file? To debug this further, you may enable [`RewriteLog`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) directive in your httpd.conf file and post the logs here.

Comment: Ah, I assume the directory does not exist and you want to map the `user` from the URI to the `/home/USER/public_html/...`, right?

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks line is  giving 500 Internal Server Error. Otherwise, interestingly, this time I am getting different errors: a)For contact: "The requested URL /contact.html was not found on this server" (instead of "/home/username/public_html/contact.html was not found on this server"). b)For index: It is showing just domain.com in bold (nothing else). ~user/ directory does exist. Actually, I had put everything under username/public_html directory.  I don't have anything else in .htcaccess.
I don't have any httpd.conf file in directory. Should I create one (sorry for being naive)?

Comment: Forget about httpd.conf for now. I updated the answer. Please try the new ruleset and report back.

Comment: Actually, it is a folder under an university domain. And this ~username directory (and the public_html folder inside it) was created by default, by the university server administrators.

Comment: Please update your question with a sample directory structure so that I know what's on the filesystem and what's not.

Comment: Done. As per your instruction.

Comment: OK, where is your htaccess file?

Comment: In public_html folder.

Comment: Is `~testuser` is already mapped to the `/home/testuser/public_html/` directory? If not, you need to put your rewrite rule in your httpd.conf. Because htaccess files only affect their residing directory and its subdirs.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I check whether ~testuser is mapped to /home/testuser/public_html/ directory?

Comment: Put an `index.html` with some test contents into its `public_html` directory and see if it's accessible via `example.com/~testuser` in your web browser.

Comment: I already have a index.html in public_html directory and it is accessible via example.com/~testuser URL.

Comment: Hi sepehr, can you please have a look again? I am still stuck at the same point.